# Bolding part of a string in an NSAlert

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, string-formatting, nsalert

I'm creating a Mac OS X app and have some issues about formatting strings on an `NSAlert`. I want the informative text to be formatted as follows :

something something something something

-------**something bold in the middle**---------

other things other things other things

So far I could only separate the lines using `\n` statement but I don't know how to make the line in the middle bold and centred. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do this, and indeed you cannot without subclassing `NSAlert`, or creating a generic window yourself. The alert can only be given a plain string, which does not include decoration information (you would need an `NSAttributedString` for that); it will do its own bolding of the text you pass.

What you can and should do is have a look at ["Alerts"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP10) in the HIG, and see that there are two strings you can supply to your alert: the "message text", which will be displayed in a bold font, and the "informative text". Make use of those to achieve a result consistent with the platform guidelines and your needs.